# How to propagate changes in the model to the view? (Using pyqt signals and slots)

Tags: python, pyqt4, signals-slots

So I have a model class that I would like to be unknowing of the fact that it's running in a pyqt application. But at the same time, when the model changes, I want the ui to update.

I would rather not have the pyqt signal in the model's code. And the observer pattern feels like too much code for just one thing that going to be listening to it.

What's a clean solution to this problem?

Comment: I don't quite understand the situation. Is the model a Qt model, or some data?

Comment: It's my own custom class. I was hoping to integrating it with pyqt without changing code in my custom class.

Comment: You can leave the class as is, but you need to write a Qt model that acts as a communicator between the view and your class. View requires certain API to access the data and Qt model will provide that interface for your custom class. Check [model/view docs](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/model-view-programming.html).

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if one of them is satisfactory. If no answer satisfies you, you can always post a comment asking for clarification.

Answer (score 4):

> And the observer pattern feels like too much code for just one thing that going to be listening to it.

Actually, the observer pattern is *exactly* what you need, and you don't have to use PyQt signal/slots at all. The "right" way to structure your code is to write the business logic have no idea about the existence of the GUI, but the GUI should have (weak) references to the business logic.

### Program structure

I usually start up my PyQt applications roughly like this:

```
import sys
import weakref
import PyQt4.QtGui as QtGui
from businesslogic import MyBusinessLogicClass
from guimodule import MyGuiClass    

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
business_object = MyBusinessLogicClass()
gui = MyGuiClass(weakref.proxy(business_object))
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note that the gui receives a reference to the business logic object (through a weak reference). The gui can therefore send data to the business logic when the human interacts with the gui.

### Getting information from the business logic to the gui

Your question was about how the business logic can get data to the gui without having explicit references to the gui in its code. I've solved this by making a decorator that I can put on functions and methods which I want the the gui to be able to know about. Suppose the business logic looks like this

```
# businesslogic.py
from observed import event  # Bear with me for a minute.

class MyBusinessLogicClass(object):
    @event
    def do_something_interesting(self, arg):
        print("logic back-end did something interesting with arg=%s"%(arg,))
```

That little decorator `@event` makes it so that other things can sign up to be notified whenever `do_something_interesting` is called. The gui does this

```
# guimodule.py

class MyGuiClass(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, business):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.business = business
        business.do_something_interesting.addObserver(self.notify)
    
    def notify(self, arg):
        <present notification to the user>
```

Note that `MyBusinessLogicClass` knows nothing about the gui. The only invasion into the code was the `@event` decorator which is completely ignorant of the GUI and in fact entirely ignorant of PyQt. Note also that the `arg` passed into `MyBusinessLogicClass` is passed along to the observing method `notify` in the GUI.

### Implementation of the observer pattern

Ok, this is all great, but it relies on the existence of something implementing the observer pattern to get that `@event` decorator. You can get my implementation, called **observed** [on GitHub](https://github.com/DanielSank/observed), or you can just do

`$ pip install observed`

If you're on windows just download the source distribution from github and then in the root directory do

`> python setup.py install`

I really do hope this is helpful. I developed **observed** specifically for this use case. It is very simple but addresses several shortcomings of other observer pattern implementations I've seen in python.

**Note:** My **observed** library is under development, so syntax may have changed a bit since this post was written.

---

**EDIT**: You said you wanted to get this all working without changing your custom class. While that is possible, you'd have to (I think) mess with the nature of your methods at run time, which is generally frowned upon because it's more confusing and fragile than doing things directly in the code. If adding the `@event` decorator to some methods is too intrusive, you can subclass your custom class and add the decorator in the subclass. You can even use a custom metaclass to apply the decorator automagically.